# convertir JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> a Json

Tags: json, java-8, apache-spark

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo de WordCount y me gustaría sacar el resultado a JSONObject:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String x) {
        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(x, 1);
    }
}).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    public Integer call(Integer x, Integer y) {
        return x + y;
    }
});

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

counts.foreach(line -> {
    json.put(line._1(), line._2());
});
```

parece que `json` queda vacía después de recorrer `counts`, como si fuera una variable interna dentro del iterador. ¿Cómo puedo sacarla fuera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> finalCounts = counts.toArray();

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    for (Tuple2<String, Integer> count : finalCounts)
        json.put(count._1(), count._2());
```